# Javascript: How to Undefine (or Redefine) a "let"-defined variable

Tags: javascript, var, let

Is it possible to undefine a `let`-defined variable so I can then redefine it?  With `var`, I can just redefine the same variable over and over again.  With `let`, a second attempt to define the variable is met with an error.

(You might wonder why I want to do this, and the reason is because I often run and re-run little one-line and multi-line scripts from my browser console, copied and pasted from elsewhere or as a bookmarklet.  If those little scripts define a variable using `let`, then a re-run of the script fails. I could just continue to use `var` in these cases, but I'm trying to embrace the new order.  And regardless of whether you think my use case is valid, the question stands.)

I've tried to `delete` it from the `window` object and some other hacks, but to no avail.

Comment: The answer is "no", but there are workarounds for your specific problem.

Comment: One workaround would be to check if it is undefined, and on only in that case define it - otherwise just assign to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type a `{` before the script and a `}` after it so that you are running the script inside a new block scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way it's specified, if you want the worse behaviour you can use var.

> Redeclaring the same variable within the same function or block scope
>   raises a SyntaxError.
>
> ```
> if (x) {
>   let foo;
>   let foo; // SyntaxError thrown.
> }
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

Let say somewhere in the code, a variable has been defined as `let a = 2` and you want to redefine it, just use `a = 3` **if** the original variable `a` is in scope. Deleting `a` from `window` won't work because definitions of `a` using `let` won't attach it to the `window` object.